# Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server - no solution found for this

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wamp

I'm trying to set SSL to my localhost server with WAMPServer 3.2.5 - 64bits  . I installed Win64 OpenSSL v3.1.2 to generate a private key and certificate by the following guides:

1. Install OpenSSL
2. Create key certificate

cd c:/openssl-win64/bin/

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048

openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key

openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 36500
```

Move the files to  conf folder in apache

3. Edit httpd.conf

go to c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/ and edit httpd:conf

Uncomment this:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

4. Edit httpd-ssl.conf File

go to c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/extra/ and edit httpd-ssl.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"

SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/certificate.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/private.key"
```

But after doing all that, I am getting:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 186 of
> C:/wamp64-new/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
> modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1.

**How can I fix this error? mod_ssl.so exist in modules folder.**